# Spark 2.4.4. library issue java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

We are currently using Databricks as the execution engine which runs spark/Scala code. This was working fine when we use spark 2.4.0 and scala 2.11

When we try to use the same code on new version of Spark 2.4.4 and Scala 2.11, we have been getting error as below,

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FilePartition.files()Lscala/collection/Seq;

Tried the below imports and still the same issue.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.expr
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
import sqlContext.implicits._
```

Comment: check your spark 2.4.4 is for scala 2.11.

Comment: Please share your dependencies/pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

Seems that scala version changed between the two versions. According to the docs:

spark 2.4.0 (https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/):

> For the Scala API, Spark 2.4.0 uses Scala 2.11. You will need to use a
>   compatible Scala version (2.11.x).

spark 2.4.4 (https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.4/):

> For the Scala API, Spark 2.4.4 uses Scala 2.12. You will need to use a
>   compatible Scala version (2.12.x).

Make sure all your dependencies are set to scala 2.12 if you use spark 2.4.4

Answer (score 0):

if you are using any jar, make sure that jar also have similar artifact for scala build. like 2.10 / 2.11 / 2.12